# What happens if vampires in Anne Rice's books drink the last drop of someone's blood?

Tags: vampire, vampire-chronicles, queen-of-the-damned

During the movie *Queen of the Damned*, Marius tells Lestat that they cannot consume the last drop of blood of someone, or else they will die too. What exactly happens if a vampire takes the last drop of blood from someone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In *Queen of the Damned*, the lore dictates that if someone drinks "the last drop of blood", they will take death - their victim's death - into themselves...

*Interview...* states that if you drink **the blood of the dead** there will be a heavy consequence (although not *necessarily* death)

The two are not necessarily mutually incompatible: *Queen*... may just be more elegiac and prosaic in the way it articulates its point.

It's very unlikely the idea of "The last drop of blood" is supposed to be literal, but rather interpreted as some form of accommodated murder. If there were literally no blood left in their victim's body, they would exhibit drastically different signs of decay and de-circulation (particularly in the scene where Marius is explaining feeding to Lestat).

Perhaps the "last drop" is just a more flowery way of saying you will drink the blood of the victim once it has died and become a cadaver, and thus incur what befalls Lestat in *Interview*....

[image]

These two films (if not the books) seem to deploy the same idea in slightly different terminology, but despite the ambiguity it could be inferred to be the same point.

Comment: But this also happens in the books?

Comment: Do you have a quote fromthe passage from the Pandora that directly quotes them as draining the blood until *he is dead*, or until the point of death, in which they stop to allow the body to die from Exsanguination?

Comment: It's been a while since I read the books, but I don't remember this bit about "the last drop of blood" being in there.  I could be mistaken though.  Also, the Queen was a MUCH different creature than most "modern" vampires, and IIRC there were several things that applied to her and not to most others, so maybe this was one of those.

Answer (score 2):

In *The Vampire Lestat,* Magnuson tells this to the newly made Lestat who, true to form, does it anyway.  All that happens is that he actually *feels* the death, and it momentarily stuns him. Not deadly in of itself, but potentially dangerous when feeding in a dark alley or some such place...a bad time to be psychically knocked senseless, so I can see an elder advising a newbie against this.

Comment: I'm on _The Vampire Lestat_ now. Being engrossed by the "vampire lore" of Anne Rice's world from _Interview with the Vampire_, I was made deeply curious by the unspoken and unanswered question "_why_ shouldn't a vampire drink after his victim's heart has stopped beating?" ...only to be bemused by Lestat breaking the rule, and experiencing...basically not much (other than what you described). Given Lestat's experience with it, I wonder why he'd bother repeating the advice to Louis or Claudia. Is this topic ever explored much more later in the book/series?